# Federsted account AWS ECS Fargate Task cannot pull secrets from SSM

Tags: parameters, amazon-ecs, store, aws-ssm, aws-fargate

I have a particular situation with Ecs Fargate, the problems is that the task can not pull secrets but everything looks good

I have created a new vpc
3 public subnets with  IG and natGateway.
3 private subnets with the local route and  a 0.0.0.0 route pointing to natGateway.
I also opened all port and IP  communication at SG just for testing.
Task execution role were granted will all privileges like Admin (just for some minutes )
I check acl and there was nothing wire .

Having say that , vpc endpoints would not be necessary.
If i run the task without parameter stores references  (1.4) it works but if I add   references to parameter store in the task environment variables it starts to fail.

After that I made another test using vpce, I created SSM, secret manager,S3,dkr and ecr.api.
Dns are also enabled at vpc level , so I should work but is not .

Also I built an additional ec2 instance and I put it in a private subnet with no public IP.
I connected to that using another bastion  I made  several request to external websites and it worked, so I can assume that the  communication with private subnet AND nat would not be an issue.
i have already configured AWS accounts on that way and it worked.

Later I ran the task in public subnet with public IP with the same result , I also run a new task in the default subnet with public IP , but nothing change.

So at this point I have no clue about where the problem can be any help will be much appreciated

The account is part of federated account

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@marcin thanks for your answer , but yes I added first all individual permission and finally I added admin rights but the problem was really ridiculous and I found the mistake.
Hope it helps , when I had to add the Arn of valueFrom  i just typed it i did not copy it from the cli Json query and I made a mistake typing the zone. I set us-east1 instead of us-east-1.
When you type a wrong variable name , the task message shows you that explicitly saying that it does not exist , but in my case looks like it  got stuck  trying to find the endpoint without advise that it does not exist .

Thanks to everyone